# JsReport .NET Core - Generate PDF from url

Tags: pdf, asp.net-core, jsreport

Trying to use JsReport to generate a pdf from a url but can't find any documentation or examples in their github repo.

Basically I need to generate the pdf and attach it to an email and I've managed to get data back as a byte[], but I can't seem to figure out how to use an existing View/Action.

This is the action that generates the PDF for viewing...

```
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(JsReportPipeline))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Pdf(Guid id)
    {
        var serviceOrder = await _serviceOrderService.Get(id);
        if (serviceOrder == null) return new NotFoundResult();

        var model = _mapper.Map<ServiceOrderModel>(serviceOrder);
        HttpContext.JsReportFeature().Recipe(Recipe.PhantomPdf);
        return View(model);
    }
```

This action should take the pdf view from "Details" and generate a PDF that I can attach. Below I can generate it with static content like "Hello from pdf" but I can't figure out how to use my "Details" view in ASPNET Core.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Email(Guid id)
    {
        var rs = new LocalReporting().UseBinary(JsReportBinary.GetBinary()).AsUtility().Create();

        var report = await rs.RenderAsync(new RenderRequest()
        {
            Template = new Template()
            {
                Recipe = Recipe.PhantomPdf,
                Engine = Engine.None,
                Content = "Hello from pdf",
            }
        });

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await report.Content.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/pdf") { FileDownloadName = "out.pdf" };
    }
```

Comment: Did you get the solution devfunkd ?

Comment: @IdrisStack I have posted an answer below, check if it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken From the [JsReport Github Dotnet Example](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-dotnet-example-webapp/blob/master/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L31),

```
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(JsReportPipeline))]
public IActionResult InvoiceDownload()
{
    HttpContext.JsReportFeature().Recipe(Recipe.ChromePdf)
        .OnAfterRender((r) => HttpContext.Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"myReport.pdf\"");

    return View("Invoice", InvoiceModel.Example());
}
```

If you want to return a file from Asp.net Core Controller Action method then try the following

```
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(JsReportPipeline))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Pdf(Guid id)
{
    var serviceOrder = await _serviceOrderService.Get(id);
    if (serviceOrder == null) return new NotFoundResult();

    var model = _mapper.Map<ServiceOrderModel>(serviceOrder);
    HttpContext.JsReportFeature().Recipe(Recipe.PhantomPdf).OnAfterRender((r) =>
       HttpContext.Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"out.pdf\"");

    return View(model);
}
```